# Estimate Gamma distribution using central limit theorem

Tags: probability-theory, central-limit-theorem, gamma-distribution

The random variable X has a Gamma distribution with parameters $ \alpha$ = na, and $ \beta$ = b , $a, b > 0$, and n a natural number different from zero.
What is the probability that X is strictly greater than $(n+1)ab$ for n big enough ?

i start with: $$ X_i > (n+1)ab$$
so: $$X_i -nab > ab $$

now divide by standard deviation of Gamma distribution:$$\frac{X_i -nab}{\sqrt {nab^2} } > \frac{a}{\sqrt {na}} $$

and now take the sum over all $X_i$'s: $$\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{X_i -nab}{\sqrt {nab^2} } > \frac{na}{\sqrt {na}} $$

and for last i multiply $ \frac{1}{\sqrt n}$ with the term above: $$\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{X_i -nab}{\sqrt {nab^2} } > \frac{na}{\sqrt {a}n} $$

or equivalently:$$\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{X_i -nab}{\sqrt {a} nb } > \frac{a}{\sqrt {a}} $$

so i get exactly the structure of central limit theorem by manipulating the fact that $X_i > (n+1)ab$ that says it is equal to standard normal distribution the left hand side is now standard normal distributed , but clearly i make a mistake some where but i don't see it! Can  someone please explain why my method doesn't work ?

Comment: "and now take the sum over all X's" Sorry but what does that mean?

Comment: @Did i edited the question up a bit , by adding indices 'i' so now it make sense to take sum over all $X_i's$

Comment: Except that $$X_i-nab>ab$$ with $X_i$ Gamma$(a,b)$, does not interest you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't quite understand your question, but I'll give it a shot.

Let $X\sim\Gamma(na,b)$, $n\in\mathbb{N}_{>1};a,b\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$. Now define iid $X_i\sim\Gamma(a,b)$, so that $$ X=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i $$
First, let $ \mu={a}{b} $ and $\sigma^2=ab^2$ (assuming shape-scale, not shape-rate, parametrization). 
Then, by the central limit theorem, 
 $$ Z = \frac{X - n\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{n}} $$
converges in distribution to the standard normal, i.e. $$ Z=\frac{X - nab}{b\sqrt{an}} \xrightarrow[\;\;\;]{\text{d}} \mathcal{N}\left(0,1\right) $$
However, it appears you are interested in the fact that [the distribution of $X/n$ is *close* to $ \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2/n) $ for large enough $n$ (verbatim from Wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Classical_CLT). Please correct me if I'm misunderstanding.

So, your original question asks for $$ p=P(X>(n+1)ab) $$
Now, for large $n$, we assume $ X\sim\mathcal{N}(n\mu,n\sigma^2) $ and so we get: $$ p=P\left( \frac{X - nab}{b\sqrt{an}} > \frac{(n+1)ab-nab}{b\sqrt{an}} \right) \approx P\left( Z > \frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{n}} \right) = 1 - \Phi\left(\sqrt{\frac{a}{n}}\,\right)$$ where $\Phi$ is the normal cdf.

Comment: Thanks, you got it right , but why you didn't multiply Z (third equation to the last by $ \frac {1}{\sqrt n}$) and i think 'a' should be over n instead of b at the last equation,  at the end. am i right ?

Comment: FYI, the assertion that $$ \frac{1}{n}X \xrightarrow[\;\;\;]{\text{d}} \mathcal{N}\left(\mu,\frac{\sigma^2}{n}\right) $$ is meaningless. Every convergence statement $$x_n\to x$$ requires that the limit $x$ does not depend on $n$. Same remark regarding $$ X \xrightarrow[\;\;\;]{\text{d}} \mathcal{N}\left(n\mu,n{\sigma^2}\right) $$

Comment: Finally, the approach you suggest, once corrected, does not lead to the limit $$1 - \Phi\left(\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}\,\right)$$ but to the limit $$\frac12$

Comment: @upvoter Please explain your vote.

Comment: Dear @Did, thanks for your comments. I agree that the "convergence" notation is misleading. All I wanted to say was that $X$ approximately follows that distribution for large enough finite $n$, and did not mean a limit to infinity. What notation do you suggest? Or am I strictly incorrect in substance as well as notation? As for the final limit being $1/2$, I think we are understanding the question differently (and indeed it is not optimally worded). The OP, I think, assumes a large but finite $n$, hence it does not disappear in the final expression. (Note: I will correct the $b$ to an $n$)

Comment: @SamFarjamirad I believe you were correct. I've replaced the $b$ with an $n$. Thanks for catching it.

Comment: Re convergence, simply use limits of the form $$x_n\to x$$ where $x$ does not depend on $n$ and everything is correct. In your case, what you actually mean is that $$\frac{X-n\mu}{\sqrt{n}}\to\mathcal N(0,\sigma^2)$$ Re the limit at the end, none of the quantities $p_n$ is exactly what you say hence your statement can only be valid in the limit $n\to\infty$ and then, what do you think your RHS $$1-\Phi\left(\sqrt{\frac{a}n}\right)$$ converges to?

Comment: Note that if really the OP is trying to get an approximation of $p_n$ for $n$ large but fixed, then no, $1-\Phi(\sqrt{a/n})$ won't do.

Comment: @user3658307 i'm almost there but why you didn't multiply the Z by the correction factor $ \frac{1}{\sqrt n} $ ? in the first expression for Z you well did it by further you didn't and i wonder why ?

Comment: and further you substitute $ \mu n$ with $nab$ but $ \mu = nab$ so it should be $ n^2 ab$ in the second expression for Z am i wrong ?

Comment: @Did I have edited the answer to remove the misleading convergences. I am aware that it will converge to $1/2$ as it moves to $1-\Phi(0)$, but the OP says he/she wants "the probability that X is strictly greater than $(n+1)ab$ for $n$ big enough". There is an $n+1$ in that term, suggesting they do not mean it to go to infinity. The question also talks about the CLT, and hence I have tried to use it. If that won't do, then what should instead be done? If there is a mistake, please expound; I would be happy to learn something new.

Comment: @SamFarjamirad I apologize, but I do not understand your question. Also, $\mu=ab$. Perhaps the edited version is better?

Comment: @user3658307 The $ \mu$ is expected value of Gamma distribution so equal to the product of its parameter in this case as you noted in the second line of your answer it is $ nab $ so the $ \mu = nab$ and then $n \mu = n^2ab$

Comment: @user3658307 we are good thanks! i got it

Comment: @Did Dear Did, by n big enough i mean $ n > 30$ or some values that practically possible and definitely not infinity but thanks to mentioned it

Comment: @SamFarjamirad Right -- hence no guarantee that the CLT applies.

Comment: @user3658307 Once again: 1. "the distribution of X/n is close to N(μ,σ2/n) for large enough n (verbatim from Wiki)" No. You chose the one formulation on the WP page which is **incorrect** (one line before, they state things correctly). 2. The second "=" sign in your last displayed string of identities is **wrong**, one can at the most state an equivalence (in a sense to be made precise). 3. There is no reason to believe that $1-\Phi(\sqrt{a/n})$ is a closer approximation of $p_n$ than $1-\Phi(42/n)$ when $n\to\infty$, or than... $1-\Phi(0)$. To believe otherwise is to **misuse** the CLT.

Comment: @Did 1. While I defer to your greater knowledge in this subject, I must respectfully disagree that it is **incorrect**. I believe the OP is coming from an applied perspective, perhaps as a non-mathematician, and this viewpoint (non-rigorous as it may be) is *a commonly taught one*. If you disagree with this, please take it up with the people teaching it, and who expect their students to know it. I am merely answering the question as the OP wanted it answered. 2. Fair enough. I have changed it to a $\approx$. I do not think there is a need for analytic precision in this context. ...

Comment: @Did ....  3. No such limit is being taken (according to the OP). I think perhaps it is better to say that we are not using the CLT; instead, we are using the "empirical observation" that for large $n$, a normal distribution serves as an approximation in this case. My apologies if this bothers you, but I prefer to answer the question and help the OP understand what they are being taught, even if it is heuristic, rather than adhere to strict notions of rigour that the asker is not interested in.

Comment: Funny how you actually *fully confirm* points 1.-2.-3.